# Parsing JSON in Android Application

Tags: android, json

Old JSON:

```
{
"listing" : [
     {
    "id" : "l101",
    "name" : "Paul"
     }
   ]
}
```

and Code to parse JSON,

```
private static final String TAG_LISTING = "listing";

    JSONArray contacts = null;

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

    try {
        contacts = json.getJSONArray(TAG_LISTING);

        for(int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++){
            JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
           }
      }
```

But my new JSON looks like below:

```
 [
     {
    "id" : "l101",
    "name" : "Paul"
     }
 ]
```

so my question, where i need to make changes in my code, to parse new JSON ?

Comment: When you parse the array, you read with `contacts = json.getJSONArray(TAG_LISTING);` which in fact reads the listings attribate instead of the full JSON array. What you want is to either write out a new `listings` array or read the array from the root-element.

Comment: your json is wrong remove comma after paul

Comment: as Vijay said your json is not valid, `,` after `Paul` make your json as invalid, but if your json is valid and this is typo mistake so you can get New JSON with `contacts = jParser.getJSONArrayFromUrl(url);`

Comment: From where you want to read json ? server or in project ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After correcting your JSON parse it like this:

```
private static final String TAG_LISTING = "listing";

JSONArray contacts = null;

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

try {

    for(int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++){
        JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(i);
       }
  }
```

Comment: `json` is `JSONObject` you can't loop that in for statement, i think your mean is `JsonArray`

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look to this tutorial: http://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/

Basically first you have to have a JSONObject and then you have to associate you JSONArray to a "name tag".